# Admin / Member login PHP not redirecting

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a login system where there is a member and a user. I have a table that has a column of name, username, password, email and type. Type designates the type of user. I have created already a working log-in form. My problem is every time I try to log in it does not redirect to the designated page. It stays on the same page but gives me a blank page. I've been figuring out what is wrong with the code. Can someone help me ? 
Thank you.

PHP Login code:

```
<?php
 include 'try_connect.php';

 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hsl = mysql_query("SELECT name, username, password, type FROM users WHERE username='$user' and password='$pass'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($hsl);
$username = $data['username'];
$password = $data['password'];
$type = $data['type'];
$name = $data['name'];
if ($user==$username && $pass==$password) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    if ($type =='admin') {
        header('Location: try_admin.php');
    }
    elseif ($type =='user') {
        header('Location:try_user.php');
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

LOG IN FORM

```
<form action="try_login.php" method="POST">
<table style="margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom: 1%;">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-family: Arial; line-height: 5px;">Username:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" style="margin-left: 10%; width: 120%; margin-bottom: 5%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="font-family: Arial;">Password:</th>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" style="margin-left: 10%; width: 120%; margin-bottom: 0%; margin-top: 10%;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="login" name="login" style="background-color: black; color: white; margin-bottom: 5%; margin-top: 0%; margin-left: 59%; border-color: #89cff0; border-style: double solid;">
```

Comment: what is in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 include 'try_connect.php';

 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hsl = mysql_query("SELECT name, username, password, type FROM users WHERE username='$user' and password='$pass'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($hsl);
$username = $data['username'];
$password = $data['password'];
$type = $data['type'];
$name = $data['name'];
if ($user==$username && $pass==$password) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    if ($type =='admin') {
        header("Location: try_admin.php");
    }
    elseif ($type =='user') {
        header("Location:try_user.php");
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: And what is the difference?

Comment: Just change singe to double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use `exit()` after `header()`. `exit()` will terminate your script immediately.

```
if ($type =='admin') {
        header('Location: try_admin.php');
        exit();
    }
    elseif ($type =='user') {
        header('Location:try_user.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Also make sure your `header()` function is called before any `html` output even before `<html>` tag